# form field value inside a message title in php

Tags: php, forms, webforms

I have a simple php script which I use in form on my website. It works fine, however in a title of a message I receive, I would like to have (next to the "Quote Request") a date taken from the field called "date". I was playing with this code but it didn't work. I know the answer is probably very simple, but I don't know php (yet). How can I do it?
Thank you for any help. The code below.

```
<?php
$addressto = "email@email.com";
$subject = "Quote Request";
$content = "Name: ".$_POST['name']."\n"
       ."Date: ".$_POST['date']."\n";

if(!$_POST['name'] || !$_POST['date']){
 header("Location: ../quote.html");
 exit;
}
$email = $_POST['email'];
if(mail($addressto, $subject, $content, 'From: Contact <'.$email.'>')){
header("Location: ../sent.html"); 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean:

```
$subject = "Quote Request - {$_POST['date']}";
```

Make sure you're validating the user input so as not to get yourself exploited!

Comment: No probs, please upvote and accept as answer if, I did indeed, answer your question :)

Answer (score 1):

#### Simple. Change this:

```
$subject = "Quote Request - " . date("d-m-Y", strtotime($_POST['date']));
```

Is this what you wanted?

Comment: i have tried the one above, works well, but thank you very much for you help and time spent.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the question correctly, this should achieve what you need:

```
<?php
$addressto = "email@email.com";
$subject = "Quote Request ".$_POST['date'];
$content = "Name: ".$_POST['name']."\n"."Date: ".$_POST['date']."\n";

if(!$_POST['name'] || !$_POST['date'])
{
    header("Location: ../quote.html");
    exit;
}
$email = $_POST['email'];
if(mail($addressto, $subject, $content, 'From: Contact <'.$email.'>'))
{
    header("Location: ../sent.html"); 
}
?>
```

Comment: just done from one of aboves, but thank you very much for your help!! thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

**Change**

$content = "Name: ".$_POST['name']."\n"
       ."Date: ".$_POST['date']."\n";

**To**

```
$content = "Name: ".$_POST['name']."\n
           Date: ".$_POST['date']."\n";
```

Comment: the one below is the one what I actually needed but thank you very much for your time and help

Answer (score 1):

If you want the date to be in the subject with "Quote Request", you could do the following:

```
$subject = "Quote Request ".$_POST['date'];
```